# How to get google map js polyline coordinates after editing?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

I am drawing a one polyline by using drawing manager(google map JS), and after completion of line drawn I am getting coordinates of polyline but when I tried to edit the drawn line , coordinates are not changing.

I am adding working stack blitz URL [Refer here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-google-maps-8nckiw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Please help me on these issue,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Added mouseup listener could solve this problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-google-maps-g5pbc9?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

```
  overlayClickListener(overlay) {
    var self =this;
    google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, "mouseup", function(event){
        self.centers = overlay
        .getPath()
        .getArray()
        .map((coord) => {
          return {
            lat: coord.lat(),
            lng: coord.lng(),
          };
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Its working Alex Yu, Thanks